# Why drop off in Google impressions?

Tags: google-analytics, impressions

I'm seeing a severe drop off in Google impressions.  See attached screenshot from Google Analytics:

[image: GA screenshot]

I haven't been able to attribute this to any changes on the site.  As you can see, this started happening on Oct 21st.  Does anyone know if this corresponds to a Google Search update?  Otherwise, does anyone have any suggests for tracking down the cause?  I'm pretty stumped.

Comment: Have you looked at your Webmaster dashboard?

Answer (score 2):

Joe, if you only can detect a drop in impressions in hits originating from Google and no decrease in hits from other sources, then you can safely assume there is no problem with your site.

I'm sure you know that the Google algorithm changes frequently, and that sites are crawled and re indexed re ranked frequently. One thing that you can do that will probably not hurt and can commonly help, is to add content.

Answer (score 1):

Google algorithm could be the reason for sudden drop in Google Search visitors. Check all your backlinks and website's content quality. If you are getting backlinks from bad websites using link forming methods and if you are using duplicate content in your website then it may be the reasons.

Read this article for more useful information: http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2203688/Sudden-Search-Traffic-Drop-6-Questions-to-Help-Diagnose-the-Cause.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for a manual action by Google. Sometimes webmasters use online backlink generator software to generate a large number of links in short time. In this procedure, it creates some bad links and Google may have penalized your website. You should check your manual action report here
[Google search console > Your website > Search Traffic > Manual Action](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/manual-action)

If you found some action, you may use Google disavow for remove bad backlinks. For more detail, read this Google support article:
[Disavow backlinks- Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en)